# appending rows to pandas dataframe results in duplicate rows

Tags: pandas

here's a MWE that illustrates a problem I'm having, where incrementally saving values to a dataframe over the course of a series of loops results in what looks like the overwriting of previous rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

saved = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['value1', 'value2'])
m = np.zeros(2)
for t in range(5):                
  for i in range(2):
      m[i] = m[i] + i + 1
  print(t)
  print(m)
  saved.loc[t] = m
print(saved)
```

The output I get is:

```
0
[1. 2.]
1
[2. 4.]
2
[3. 6.]
3
[4. 8.]
4
[5. 10.]

value1  value2
0   2.0 4.0
1   2.0 4.0
2   3.0 6.0
3   4.0 8.0
4   5.0 510.0
```

Why is the first row of the `saved` dataframe not `1.0, 2.0`?

Edit:
Here's another articulation of the problem, now using lists for saving then configuring as dataframe at end. The following code in a .py script

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

saved_list = []

m = np.zeros(2)

for t in range(5):                
    for i in range(2):
        m[i] = m[i] + i + 1
    print(t)
    print(m)
    saved_list.append(m)
       
saved = pd.DataFrame(saved_list, columns = ['value1', 'value2'])
print(saved)
```

gives this output from the command line:

```
0
[1. 2.]
1
[2. 4.]
2
[3. 6.]
3
[4. 8.]
4
[ 5. 10.]
   value1  value2
0     5.0    10.0
1     5.0    10.0
2     5.0    10.0
3     5.0    10.0
4     5.0    10.0
```

Why are the previous saved_list items being overwritten?

Comment: Note this is a very inefficient way to build a large DataFrame; new arrays have to be created (copying over the existing data) when you append a row.

Comment: `t is worth noting however, that concat (and therefore append) makes a full copy of the data, and that constantly reusing this function can create a significant performance hit. If you need to use the operation over several datasets, use a list comprehension.` (from Pandas' documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that making a copy of the array within the loop for saving solves both scenarios.
For the first, I used
`saved.loc[t] = m.copy()` and for the second I used `saved_list.append(m.copy())`.
It may be obvious to some that when the array is defined outside the loop, the items saved to either the list or the frame are pointers to the original item so anything saved within the loop ends up pointing to the final version.
Now I know.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected without any change. This is a print screen from Google Colab.

[image]

Comment: Now that's interesting, I wonder why different environments produce different results . . . I'm using Python 3.9.12 on JupyterLab.

Comment: And it's not just output, when I write to file previous rows are still overwritten with later values.

Comment: @zazizoma did you run the code in one Jupyter cell as I run?

Comment: yes, a single cell, and also with a fresh kernel.

Comment: I don't believe this is a Jupyter issue: putting the above into a script (with print(saved)) and running from the command line also gives the problematic output.